# How to make TIFF output file with coordinate reference system (CRS)

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, matlab, median

I am working on TIFF files to produce the median matrix for them, I am using the following Matlab code for that.
How I can make the output as .tif while keeping the coordinate reference system (CRS)?

```
unzip Test3.zip
% Warning: Cannot open file "" for reading.
files = dir('*.tif');
filenames = fullfile({files.folder},{files.name});
N = numel(files);
sz = zeros(N,2);
for ii = 1:N
    files(ii).data = imread(filenames{ii});
    sz(ii,:) = size(files(ii).data);
end
datablock = cat(3, files.data);
image_median = median(datablock, 3, 'omitnan');
[min(image_median(:)), max(image_median(:))]
image(image_median)
```

link to subsample of the data
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/u7ysb91awhih29ery4txa/Test3.zip?rlkey=7eh80xf0rshh445vhyv0w0pne&dl=0